# How to make two widgets collide closer kivy

Tags: kivy

I have two moving widgets (ellipses) on one widget and a function that defines what to do when they collide that works fine but leaves a lot of space between them when they collide.

I don't think all the code matters because its quite a lot of it.

The widgets are basically constructed like this:

```
class Snake(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos

class EvilSnake(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

class SnakeGame(Widget):
    evil_snaky = ObjectProperty(None)
    snaky = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SnakeGame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1/60.) 


    def begin(self, vel=(1, 0), *args):
        #begin method

    def game_over(self, *args):
        # game over method


    def update(self, dt, *args):
        #methodes for movement


        #snakes collide:
        if self.snaky.collide_widget(self.evil_snaky):
            self.game_over()
```

.kv part:

```
<Snake>:
    size: 50, 50 
    canvas:
        Color: 
            rgba: 1,1,1,1
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<EvilSnake>:
    size: 50, 50
    canvas: 
        Color: 
            rgba: 1,1,1,1
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<SnakeGame>:
    snaky: snake
    evil_snaky: evilsnake
    # canvas instructions
    Snake: 
        id: snake
        center: self.parent.center  
    EvilSnake:
        id: evilsnake
        center: self.parent.center[0]-70, self.parent.center[1]
```

They collide and the collide method does do what it should, but a lot quicker I would have wanted. When they collide it looks like this:
http://postimg.org/image/uir5jqpht/

Is there any simple way to make them collide really close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write your own collision function that performs whatever proximity test you like, and call that instead. The builtin method just does a simple check against the rectangular widget boundaries.

You could override the existing method with this, but it doesn't really matter and probably is a matter of taste.

(Edit: based on your image, perhaps you want circle collision, calculate the distance between the centres of the two widgets and return True if it's less than the sum of their radii, which is probably equal to the width of either of them if they're square and the circle fills the widget.)

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I wanted!